# Pushed virtual environment folder on github

Tags: python, github

I pushed my venv folder in github and now I want to remove it.

Doing git revert I have to click on y/n for all the files (>3k). Which is very annoying and I thought to add venv/ in .gitignore file and pushing the code again thinking it would remove it automatically but it didn't.

Comment: `git revert commit` will simply revert that commit. It's not clear what exactly you committed in addition, so voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) tool for that.

1. Install filter-repo tool from their official repository.
2. Run the following command in your project folder:

> git filter-repo --path path-to-file --invert-paths
> 3. Force push the branch:
> git push origin branch-name --force

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm --cached -r venv*
```

after this do `commit` and `push`